# nginx configuration rewrite not working

Tags: nginx

Having the following nginx config:

```
server {
  server_name home.example.com;

  listen 80;

  location /rocket/ {
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_pass http://IP:3010/;
      proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

I'm serving a web chat running internally on port 3010 to the URL `home.example.com/rocket`

The first GET request is OK because it's being redirected well, but when the HTML page ask for the CSS and JS scripts it is using the root server name:

`home.example.com/asdfsafdsf.css`

without the `/rocket` path.

Is there a rewrite rule or something similar that returns the first HTML telling that all the following requests must be made adding the `/rocket` path?

Comment: This is usually configured in the application server settings.

Comment: Yes, I can do it in the app, however I'm wondering if this is possible via the proxy configuration

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you configure this in the proxy the proxy has to rewrite the content of the HTML for each request before serving it. This adds additional load to the proxy which is completely unnecessary when the application server can directly generate the proper HTML.

Comment: I just don't want to change the app source code because it should not depend on where it's deployed

Comment: Of course you should not change the source code. This usually is a configuration option, either in the application itself, or in the application server.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I have found this https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/running-in-a-sub-folder/. I will try to mimic this in the nginx conf

Comment: That is exactly what I was advising against. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Don't configure this in Nginx, configure this in the application server.

The [reverse proxy documentation of RocketChat](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/configuring-ssl-reverse-proxy/) has a note about this:

> Note: You must use the outside https address for the value at ROOT_URL in [[Section 3 Deploy-Rocket.Chat-without-docker#3-download-rocketchat]] above. This includes the https:// and leave off the port number. So instead of **ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000** use something like **https://your_hostname.com**

So, edit your RocketChat configuration and set

```
ROOT_URL=http://home.example.com/rocket/
```

After that there is no need to mess with the Nginx config about this.

Comment: I will try it!!